# Creating schedule layout with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to dynamicaly generate schedules that will look like on the picture below:

[image: Schedule]

As you see on the picture, some columns need to be longer than the others. This produces *the problem of stacking divs on top of each-other without breaking the schedule structure*. So, what is the best way to populate such table and overcome the mentioned problem?

I have several ideas regarding this issue, but none of them seem right to me. Here they are:

**1)** I could calculate which column is the longest and add the same amount of cells to every column, filling some of them with the data afterwards.

**pros** of this approach:

- Simple to implement
- Table structure is preserved

**cons**:

- Unused cells will be added to the table

**2)** It is possible to avoid adding the extra cells to the table by leveraging `col-offsets`, but the idea of calculating which cells need the `col-offset` added to them seems rather painful.

**3)** I could use real tables, instead of hacking around with divs, but every time I try to use them, I end up with a broken page structure.

Please suggest how would you deal with this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's quite simple to stack columns on top of each other:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <p>YOUR CONTENT</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <p>YOUR CONTENT</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <p>YOUR CONTENT</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The trick is to wrap a row inside a parent column that is sized according to your needs (`col-xs-3` in this case). After this, just add columns with size `*-12` to the mentioned row, forcing them to wrap and jump down, but be contained inside the outer `col-xs-3` column.

Comment: nice trick, but shouldn't the outer div be a higher class (col-md-3 or lg-3)? Using xs-3 will make this structure REALLY small on a mobile screen. shouldnt it be that each column will be full width on a mobile and display horizontally on a larger screen? And also - are the inner col-xs-12's necessary? since theya re wrapped in a "row" and the "p" elements are block level elements that will display to the full width of their container (the row)?

Comment: Nice point @gavgrif, but in my current project I'm not concerned with responsiveness and didn't think about it. This example could be adapted to your needs though. As of the "p" elements, you may have a lot more complex structure wrapped into a div instead of the sample text present on the example. By nesting the cols, you utilize bootstrap's capabilities and stay "inside the framework", which is good thing to do IMHO. Certainly, you could make your own custom styles if the need ever arose :)